# Why Analytics showing non existing pages in active pages?

Tags: google, google-analytics, backlinks, sitelinks, blackhat

I am facing weired suitation in my analytics tool ,

My website getting referrals from a porn site and I can see some porn related pages in active page section in analytic report ( both in real-time as well as history ) .

All the showin pages never exist on my website and my page content and pages are related to financial but this analytics ( snapshot ) showing  visitors landed at porn content page (

7. /www.youporn-forum.ga/post419325    www.youporn-forum.ga/post419325 1
   10.00%

[image]

I dont know how this page generated in my website ...

why this is happening , will this affect my website ??

Thank you

Comment: Can you see these referrals in your site log files?? It is possible that it is a ghost referrer in which case, there is nothing you can fix or will really hurt you. Otherwise, you can simply 404 error these in your .htaccess or other mechanism.

Comment: A great answer is found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717151/why-are-porn-stuff-sites-appearing-on-my-google-analytics-data.

Comment: I have them too, i seems the webpage is suspended now by the domain name register

Answer (score 2):

That is likely due to referral spam. A spammer is likely using your Google Analytics tracking ID so that activities on their own website end up getting recorded in your own Analytics account. To check, assign "hostname" as your secondary dimension when checking your data and you will see which website is actually the culprit.

To get rid of your spam data and ensure that only actual visits to your website get recorded, create a hostname filter:

1. Go to "Admin".
2. Click on "Filters".
3. Click on "New Filter".
4. Tick "Create New Filter".
5. Specify your "Filter Name" (ex. Spam Remover).
6. Select "Custom".
7. Select "Include Only" for the "Filter Type".
8. Select "Traffic to the Hostname" for the "Source or Destination".
9. Select "That Contain" for the "Expression".
10. And then under "Hostname", indicate your domain name with a `\` before any period. (ex. if your site is `http://www.mysite.com.au`, then it will be `mysite\.com\.au`)

And then that's it. Google Analytics will then show you only visits that really ended up on pages with your domain name.

Comment: 6) Setting is not custom but predefined and does not pass filter verification.

Answer (score -1):

You can also try to block the referral traffic via the .htaccess page on your hosting.
For example you can add the following lines to your .htaccess while replacing the "domainnamex.yyy" with thes spammy website:

```
##Ban spams
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} domainname0.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} domainname1.org [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} domainname2.com.tw [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```